# How to loosen up Tris HCl?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have this bottle of Tris HCl that I need to use and apparently it's all hard. I don't have time to get a new bottle since this is needed for a lab for tomorrow and this is all I was given. Is there an easy way of loosening it up to be free flowing short of throwing the bottle around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try warming the bottle gently in an oven or hot water bath (not on a dry hot plate!) - I would try 50 C for starters. If it is in a plastic bottle I would avoid getting it too hot. Maybe it will soften, like brown sugar, and then you could scoop it out with a spatula.

Alternatively, you could weigh the entire bottle, use the contents to prepare a stock solution of known volume, measure the tare weight of the now-empty bottle, calculate the concentration of the stock solution, and use it to prepare buffers of known TRIS concentration.